# sequential equivalence with more than one multi bit register

Tags: yosys

extremely simple sequential logic equivalence test case:

```
module memory1(
    input   wire        clk,
    input   wire        srst,
    input   wire [15:0] addr,
    input   wire        din,
    input   wire        wr,
    input   wire        rd,

    output  reg  [15:0] out
);

reg [15:0] mem;

always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
    if (srst) begin
        mem <= 'd0;
        out <= 'd0;
    end
    else begin
        if (wr) mem[addr] <= din;
        out <= mem;
    end
end
endmodule
```

And then:

```
module memory2(
    input   wire        clk,
    input   wire        srst,
    input   wire [15:0] addr,
    input   wire        din,
    input   wire        wr,
    input   wire        rd,

    output  reg  [15:0] out
);

reg [15:0] mem;

always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
    if (srst) begin
        mem <= 'd0;
        out <= 'd0;
    end
    else begin
        if (wr) case (addr)
            'd0 : mem[0] <= din;
            'd1 : mem[1] <= din;
            'd2 : mem[2] <= din;
            'd3 : mem[3] <= din;
            'd4 : mem[4] <= din;
            'd5 : mem[5] <= din;
            'd6 : mem[6] <= din;
            'd7 : mem[7] <= din;
            'd8 : mem[8] <= din;
            'd9 : mem[9] <= din;
            'd10 : mem[10] <= din;
            'd11 : mem[11] <= din;
            'd12 : mem[12] <= din;
            'd13 : mem[13] <= din;
            'd14 : mem[14] <= din;
            'd15 : mem[15] <= din;
        endcase
        out <= mem;
    end
end
endmodule
```

using the yosys script:

```
read_verilog -sv example_mem.sv
proc
memory
miter -equiv -flatten memory1 memory2 miter
hierarchy -top miter
sat -maxsteps 50 \
    -set in_srst 0 -set-at 1 in_srst 1 \
    -show-ports \
    -seq 1 \
    -tempinduct \
    -prove trigger 0 \
    miter
```

I can get an equivalence match, all is good.

However if I change both designs such that

```
out <= mem;
```

is replaced with:

```
else if (rd) out <= mem;
```

I get a non-equivalence.

however if I use the following method, I get a pass......

```
read_verilog -sv example_mem.sv
proc
memory
equiv_make memory1 memory2 equiv
hierarchy -top equiv
flatten
equiv_induct -seq 1
equiv_status -assert
```

Can anybody shed any light for me?
why does the miter method fail with the simple mod?

Answer (score 0):

In temporal induction, this is essentially trying to prove that after starting in random states, assuming they are equal (with equal inputs) for N cycles, then they will always be equal at cycle N+1. When you add the read enable, there are paths through the design where state never "leaks" to the output so this technique no longer works.

A 50-cycle bounded model check (removing `-tempinduct` and `-maxsteps`, and setting `-seq` to 50), does pass as expected.

The second script passes because the `equiv_` commands look into the design, and adds an extra check that the two `mem` registers are identical, which then allows induction to start off "synchronised" and pass.

This is in the context of assertion verification, rather than equivalence checking, but https://zipcpu.com/blog/2018/03/10/induction-exercise.html also discusses a similar problem with temporal induction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  If I change the miter script to:  "sat -set in_srst 0 -set-at 1 in_srst 1 \
    -seq 50 \
    -prove trigger 0 \
    miter "  then I still get a fail

Comment: Setting up time step 50:
Import set-constraint: \in_srst = 1'0
Final constraint equation: \in_srst = 1'0
Imported 140 cells to SAT database.
Import proof-constraint: \trigger = 1'0
Final proof equation: \trigger = 1'0

Solving problem with 89862 variables and 249517 clauses..
SAT proof finished - model found: FAIL!